# how to list the tags of a git branch?

Tags: git

How can I list the tags that are associated with commits from a given branch ? It would do something like:

```
$ git show-all-tags dumpling ^master
v0.67
v0.67.1
v0.67.2
```

because these three tags reference commits that belong to the dumpling branch, after it was diverged from master.

Answer (score -1):

$ git log --simplify-by-decoration --decorate --pretty=oneline ceph/master..ceph/dumpling | fgrep 'tag: '
bc8b67bef6309a32361be76cd11fb56b057ea9d2 (tag: v0.67.11) 0.67.11
9d446bd416c52cd785ccf048ca67737ceafcdd7f (tag: v0.67.10) 0.67.10
ba340a97c3dafc9155023da8d515eecc675c619a (tag: v0.67.9) 0.67.9
ffc58b4ea6a3ea10e91050aaa28d14d87dea5656 (tag: v0.67.8) 0.67.8
d7ab4244396b57aac8b7e80812115bbd079e6b73 (tag: v0.67.7) v0.67.7
c71f8a60cf49fb3d4efb5ea75b2366cd7f167497 (tag: v0.67.6) release build 67.6
a60ac9194718083a4b6a225fc17cad6096c69bd1 (tag: v0.67.5) v0.67.5
ad85b8bfafea6232d64cb7ba76a8b6e8252fa0c7 (tag: v0.67.4) v0.67.4
408cd61584c72c0d97b774b3d8f95c6b1b06341a (tag: v0.67.3) v0.67.3
eb4380dd036a0b644c6283869911d615ed729ac8 (tag: v0.67.2) v0.67.2
e23b817ad0cf1ea19c0a7b7c9999b30bed37d533 (tag: v0.67.1) v0.67.1